# Отправить несколько вложений из формы

Tags: php, циклы

Есть форма, в ней несколько `<input type="file" name="foto[]" multiple id="foto" class="w100" accept="image/*">`.

Вот это часть кода с циклом для прикрепления вложений:

```
$message .= "--$baseboundary\r\n";
 for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['foto']['name']);$i++) {
     if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'][$i])) {
        $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'][$i])));
        $attachname = $nomer."-".$login."-".$_FILES['foto']['name'][$i];
        $filetype = $_FILES['foto']['type'][$i];
        $filesize += $_FILES['foto']['size'][$i];
        $message .="--$boundary\r\n";
        $message .= "Content-Type: \"$filetype\"; name=\"$attachname\"\r\n";
        $message .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $message .="Content-Disposition: attachment; \r\n";
        $message .=" filename=\"$attachname\"\r\n\r\n"; 
        $message .= $attachment;  
     }
   }
$message .= "--$baseboundary--\r\n";
```

Но в результате на почту приходит только первый прикрепленный файл... Цикл как-то неправильно оформлен?

Comment: Попробуйте заменить count($_FILES['foto']['name']) на count($_FILES['foto'])

Comment: @lyhoshva пробую, все равно только первый файл прикрепляет

Comment: еще можно попробывать изменить все поля $_FILES['foto']['attr'][$i] на $_FILES['foto'][$i]['attr']